# Variant selector is not responsing (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, shopify, selector, variant

Hey there I just added my own variant selector on product page. But it is not responsing. It is not changing the price.The old one is working fine but my variant selector is not working. I think its js code problem.

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
var $addToCart = $('#button-cart'),
    $addToCartBuy = $('#button-cart-buy'),
    $addToCartSticky = $('#button-cart-sticky'),
    $productPrice = $('#productPrice'),
    $comparePrice = $('#comparePrice'),
    $variantQuantity = $('#variantQuantity'),
    $quantityElements = $('.quantity-selector, label + .js-qty'),
    $addToCartText = $('#button-cart'),
    $featuredImage = $('#productPhotoImg');
if (variant) {
 // Regardless of stock, update the product price
        Shopify.money_format = '{{shop.money_format }}'; 

        //var customPrice = timber.formatMoney( Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price,Shopify.money_format) );
        var a11yPrice = Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, Shopify.money_format);
        // var customPriceFormat = ' <span aria-hidden="true">' + customPrice + '</span>';
        var customPriceFormat = ' <span class="visually-hidden">' + a11yPrice + '</span>';
        $productPrice.html(customPriceFormat);

        // Also update and show the product's compare price if necessary
        {% if settings.product_show_compare_at_price %}
        if ( variant.compare_at_price > variant.price ) {
          var a11yComparePrice = Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, Shopify.money_format);
          comparePriceFormat = ' <span class="visually-hidden">' + a11yComparePrice + '</span>';
          $comparePrice.html(comparePriceFormat);
          $comparePrice.show();
        } else {
          $comparePrice.hide();
        }
        {% endif %} } 
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      var product = {{ product | json }};
      new Shopify.OptionSelectors('productSelect', {
        product: product,
        onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
        enableHistoryState: true
      });


    });
```

What should I change here for my variant selector to work?

Comment: Are you sure this callback fired when you change the variant?

Comment: Hey there I found the problem today, schema was incorrect in section file. I restrored the schema now selector is working.